# How to center align inside container and get uniform width

Tags: html, css, center

I need to horizontally center align all the content shown in the image below.

I need also to make all the table cells at the same width, since it seems that they are auto adjusting according to the font awesome icon size.

How can I make this?

[My CSS here](https://jsfiddle.net/Pumizo/x94pLLhw/)

[image]

My HTML

```
<section id="Four" class="wrapper style3">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="two columns">
                                    <i class="fa fa-truck fa-5x"></i>
                                    <h3>A Fleet of</h3>
                                    <div class="counter col_fourth">
                                    <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="120" data-speed="2000"></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="text-box">TRUCKS</p>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="two columns">
                                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
                                    <h3>Involving</h3>
                                    <div class="counter col_fourth">
                                    <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="160" data-speed="2000"></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="text-box">EMPLOYEES</p>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="two columns">
                                    <i class="fa fa-cubes fa-5x"></i>
                                    <h3>Loading</h3>
                                    <div class="counter col_fourth">
                                    <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="6686" data-speed="2000"></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="text-box">FTL LOADS IN 2016</p>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="two columns">
                                    <i class="fa fa-leaf fa-5x"></i>
                                    <h3>Emissions</h3>
                                    <div class="counter col_fourth">
                                    <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="100" data-speed="2000"></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="text-box">100% EURO 6</p>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="two columns">
                                    <i class="fa fa-compress fa-5x"></i>
                                    <h3>Trailers</h3>
                                    <div class="counter col_fourth">
                                    <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="160" data-speed="2000"></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="text-box">TRAILERS</p>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="two columns">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-5x"></i>
                                    <h3>Since</h3>
                                    <div class="counter col_fourth">
                                    <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="1991" data-speed="2000"></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="text-box">25 YEARS OF SERVICE</p>
                                </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: Can we see you CSS?

Comment: can you add your css as well

Comment: @Valentino Kozinec

My bad sorry... here it is:
https://jsfiddle.net/Pumizo/x94pLLhw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox with `flex-grow` and `flex-basis` to make the columns equal width and fill the row.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row .columns {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  margin: 0 1em;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="Four" class="wrapper style3">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-truck fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>A Fleet of</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="120" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">TRUCKS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Involving</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="160" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">EMPLOYEES</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-cubes fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Loading</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="6686" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">FTL LOADS IN 2016</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-leaf fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Emissions</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="100" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">100% EURO 6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-compress fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Trailers</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="160" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">TRAILERS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Since</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="1991" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">25 YEARS OF SERVICE</p>
        </div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Or you can give the columns a specific width, and use `justify-content` to center them

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row .columns {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 1em;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="Four" class="wrapper style3">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-truck fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>A Fleet of</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="120" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">TRUCKS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Involving</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="160" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">EMPLOYEES</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-cubes fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Loading</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="6686" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">FTL LOADS IN 2016</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-leaf fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Emissions</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="100" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">100% EURO 6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-compress fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Trailers</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="160" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">TRAILERS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Since</h3>
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="1991" data-speed="2000"></h2>
          </div>
          <p class="text-box">25 YEARS OF SERVICE</p>
        </div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: there's something strange with your solution. With works fine on Dreamweaver but not on Google Chrome. It just stays the same at the browser. 

Also, it indicates the following errors on a code validator. Any advice?
`Don't use IDs in selector`

Comment: @Pumizo you don't have to use the ID's I used in my selectors, I just put them in there so the code would be limited to the parent in your example. I took them out. You'll need to limit it on your own then, assuming the classes I'm styling are common elsewhere. Dunno what to tell you re: why it isn't working. This code works in google chrome just fine (I'm using chrome now), so it's probably some sort of troubleshooting on your site and the way you implemented it.

Comment: I'm getting desperate! Everything looks great in Dreamweaver and in Snippet but no effect on Chrome or Firefox! :(

Check here how it shows on Dreamweaver:
https://picload.org/image/rowpilgr/div.jpg

Check here how it shows on Browsers:
https://picload.org/image/rowpiwra/no-fix.jpg

Complete Snippet for trying to help:
https://jsfiddle.net/Pumizo/vpzmozfL

Answer (score 0):

You sould use margin: auto; for your inner or container class

```
.inner {
     ...
     margin: auto;
     ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest using `display:flex;`.

here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/znggcgaq/

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row .columns {
  margin: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Here is a nice guide how it works: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

In my example, I am allowing the items to wrap within the container div.

Comment: "Paul Allen Seems the perfect solution for me, but it's messing with other columns on the site. How to make this settings "unique" in the CSS?

Comment: @Pumizo You will want to add some specific classes to your rows and columns. like `<div class="row services"> <div class="two columns services">` And in your CSS put something like this `.row.services{}` and .columns.services{}` The CSS rules will only apply if a div has both the classes, `row` and `services`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the final steps of my problem, based on another question I had made here: [CSS3 priority order for browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315028/css3-priority-order-for-browsers?noredirect=1#comment71784538_42315028)

I've used the tips posted above like this:

```
#statistics .row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
    }

    #statistics .row .columns {
            width: 150px;
            margin: 0 1em;
            background: #fff;
    }
```

But after this everything was looking good on Dreamweaver, but not in browsers. The problem was the CSS instructions order, because they were not the last in the "grid" CSS section. I've placed them as being the last of the CSS section and it's final centered as I wanted to